# How to check supported architectures for my framework in terminal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, architecture

I want to know which architectures are supports my framework.

I referred some of stack overflow questions and tried like this in terminal

```
lipo -info /Users/admin/library/myFramework.framework
```

But I didn't get any solution.

How to solve my problem.

Answer (score 7):

**lipo -info pathToFramework/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework**

you may get an error like

*xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see man xcode-select)*
[image]

select command Line tools

after this try again

**lipo -info pathToFramework/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework**

Answer (score 4):

In Terminal:

```
file /path/to/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
```

Example output:

```
path/to//MyFramework.framework/MyFramework: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures
path/to//MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
path/to//MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
path/to//MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (for architecture armv7):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
path/to//MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (for architecture armv7s):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
path/to//MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library
```